# Putty SSH-Connection doesn't show plots from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, putty

I am connecting to a Server via Putty and I need to plot some stuff. I am using windows on my PC and it is linux on the server.
Is there a way to see the plots on my PC when I run a script from the SSH-connection?
I tried every possible argument for the `matplotlib.use()` and it is still not working.

These `GTK3Agg, GTK3Cairo, MacOSX, nbAgg, Qt4Agg, Qt4Cairo, Qt5Agg, Qt5Cairo, TkAgg, TkCairo, WebAgg, WX, WXAgg, WXCairo` give me this error

```
Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:41:41.238: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
```

And  these `agg, cairo, pdf, pgf, ps, svg, template` give me no error, but also no output.

Is it even possible to get a plot when you use Putty for connection to anther sever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY (and other TTY clients) are just that - teletype. You cannot create windows in them because they aren't capable of graphics. The best solution for seeing these plots would be to [save the plot as an image file](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-save-figure-to-image-file/) and then [transfer it via FTP or something](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Or, if your remote machine is already running a graphical environment, you could try using VNC or another remote desktop with graphics capability.